# Convert between UTF:s without intermediate encoding

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, utf

Is it possible to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 without first decoding into UCS-4 and then encode the resulting code-point, without using a large mapping table?

Comment: What is the language you are using?  I think it is possible in one way 8 -> 16 but it is not possible 16 -> 8 without lose information.  (You can put 1 byte in 2 bytes but you can't put 2 bytes in 1 byte)

Comment: @CrApHeR I ask for an algorithm. UTF-8 coded values may use 4 bytes as well...

Comment: Generally you can convert any encoding to any encoding directly if you have the required mapping tables. Since creating an individual mapping table between every single encoding pairing is exponential and mostly pointless, one standard intermediary is being used. So to answer your question: yes, it's possible. Whether anyone has already done the necessary legwork is somewhat beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: @CrApHeR: Both are variable-length encodings. The bit width is only per coding unit.

Comment: @deceze I was looking for some bit-fiddeling. Both of these encodings can be converted to and from UCS-4 by bit-fiddeling. But what about between them.

Comment: Again, I don't know if anyone has actually done the legwork on this yet. Worst case you could implement the UTF-16→UCS-4→UTF-8 bit fiddling steps as one algorithm, then mathematically reduce the steps needed by optimising the algorithm.

Comment: Why do you want to skip the intermediate representation?  Are you trying to reduce memory usage or improve speed?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is more interesting than the comments suggest:

- UTF-8 -> UTF-16: It's not possible if you write UTF-16 word by word (if you write byte by byte, I think it depends on UTF-16LE vs. UTF-16BE). UTF-8 encodes 7 bit with 1 byte, 11 bit with 2 bytes (5/6 bit), 16 bit with 3 bytes (4/6/6 bit) and 21 bit with 4 bytes (3/6/6/6). The only interesting case is where you read more than 16 bit, exceding the first UTF-16 word, i.e. 21 bit. Unfortunately, the first four UTF-8 bytes contain only 15 bit (3 + 6 + 6), so you can't write the first UTF-16 word until you have read all four bytes. So there is no difference to decoding to UCS-4 first.
- UTF-16 -> UTF-8: After reading the first word, you know whether you are above 0xffff, in which case you get the leading 11 bit and the total number of bits, and you know it's more than 16. So in this case you can write the first two UTF-8 bytes already (3+6=9 bit).